# Docker - can't connect to php7.0-fpm.sock

Tags: magento2, docker, devops

I'm trying to set up a [Magento2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html) dev environment on [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) with PHP7 & nginx but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ docker logs --details mymagento2docker_nginx_1
 2016/10/04 19:18:31 [crit] 7#7: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: magento2.docker, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "magento2.docker"
 172.17.0.1 - - [04/Oct/2016:19:18:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I imagine it is because I don't have `upstream fastcgi_backend` configured correctly in my `nginx container` or that it isn't installed in my `php container`.

I also can't find the `php7.0-fpm.sock` within the `php container`.  I've tried looking for it with:

```
$ docker-compose ps
            Name                          Command             State                   Ports            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mymagento2docker_app_1          true                          Exit 0                               
mymagento2docker_data_1         docker-entrypoint.sh true     Exit 0                               
mymagento2docker_mysql_1        docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp      
mymagento2docker_nginx_1        nginx -g daemon off;          Up       443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp 
mymagento2docker_php_1          php-fpm                       Up       9000/tcp                    
mymagento2docker_phpmyadmin_1   /run.sh phpmyadmin            Up       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp        

$ docker exec -it mymagento2docker_php_1 /bin/bash
root@e220b07a7124:/var/www/html# php -v
PHP 7.0.11 (cli) (built: Sep 23 2016 21:47:48) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

root@e220b07a7124:/var/www/html# ls /var/run/php
ls: cannot access /var/run/php: No such file or directory

root@e220b07a7124:/var/www/html# ls /var/run/   
exim4  lock  utmp

root@e220b07a7124:/var/www/html# find / -name "*sock"            
/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vsock
/sys/class/misc/vsock
/sys/module/vsock
/sys/module/hv_sock

root@e220b07a7124:/var/www/html# find / -type d -path /var/www/html -prune -o -name "php"
/usr/local/lib/php
/usr/local/etc/php
/usr/local/include/php
/usr/local/bin/php
/usr/local/php
/usr/local/php/php
/var/www/html
```

---

### This is my Docker Project set up:

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── magento2
│   ├── [Lots ommited...]
│   ├── [Lots ommited...]
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── default.conf
│   └── nginx.conf
└── php
    └── Dockerfile
```

---

### docker-composer.yml

```
# http://tech.osteel.me/posts/2015/12/18/from-vagrant-to-docker-how-to-use-docker-for-local-web-development.html#installation
# composer create-project --ignore-platform-reqs --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2

nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - app

php:
    build: ./php/
    expose:
        - 9000
    links:
        - mysql
    volumes_from:
        - app

app:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./magento2:/var/www/html
    command: "true"

mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes_from:
        - data
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"        
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mage2
        MYSQL_DATABASE: mage2
        MYSQL_USER: mage2
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: mage2 

data:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/mysql
    command: "true"

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    links:
        - mysql
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
```

---

### php Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
    cron \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
    libxslt1-dev

# Configure the gd library
RUN docker-php-ext-configure \
  gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/

# Install required PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
  gd \
  intl \
  mbstring \
  mcrypt \
  pdo_mysql \
  xsl \
  zip \
  soap

# Install the 2.4 version of xdebug that's compatible with php7
RUN pecl install -o -f xdebug-2.4.0
```

---

### nginx Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

---

### nginx default.conf

```
# Example configuration:
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    #  use tcp connection
    server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    # I"ve also tried the below...
    # server  127.0.0.1:9000;
    # server  fpm:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name magento2.docker;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/;
    set $MAGE_MODE default;

    root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

    index index.php;
    autoindex off;
    charset off;

    add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options' 'nosniff';
    add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1; mode=block';

    location /setup {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;
        location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
            fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    location /update {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;

        location ~ ^/update/index.php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny everything but index.php
        location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /pub {
        location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
            deny all;
        }
        alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /static/ {
        if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
            expires max;
        }
        location ~ ^/static/version {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }
        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires    off;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
               rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /media/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

        location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires    off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /media/customer/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/downloadable/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/import/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ cron\.php {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=512M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

---

### nginx nginx.conf

user root;
    worker_processes 1;

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;

  keepalive_timeout 65;

  fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

  gzip on;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In nginx configuration try use

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server  php:9000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I also can't find the php7.0-fpm.sock within the php container. I've tried looking for it with:

I think You miss  php7.0-fpm extension in this docker, Check you installed or not php7.0-fpm in docker

if you installed php7.0-fpm in docker go to php info Which **php.ini** file used in php.

Nginx + magento2 Need **/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini** file not /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

If you Php used **/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini** then go to **/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**

change

```
    listern = 127.0.0.1 :9000
```

to

```
    listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

then only create php7.0-fpm.sock file.

After Restart the php7.0-fpm.

```
    service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Now to go **nginx default.conf**  change below line.

```
    upstream fastcgi_backend {
        #  use tcp connection
        server   unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;  
    }
```

Now Check it. I hope this is useful for you,  Same Problem Occur Before, I try to change this, its worked for me. If you have any issue after change this configuration,  let me know

Answer (score 0):

I'm using laradock and faced the same issue. Solution for me was the following:

Change all lines `fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;` `to fastcgi_pass   php-upstream;`
and don't use `upstream fastcgi_backend {...}` section